# About Python pygame font.SysFont

Tags: python, fonts, pygame

```
font = pygame.font.Font.render(None, 25)

def message_to_screen(msg, color):
    screen_text = font.render(msg, True, color)
    screen.blit(screen_text, [display_width/2, display_height/2])

while not game_exit:
    for event in pygame.event.get():
        if event.type == QUIT:
            game_exit = True

        if event.type == pygame.KEYDOWN:
            if event.key == pygame.K_LEFT:
                lead_x_change = -moving_speed
            if event.key == pygame.K_RIGHT:
                lead_x_change = moving_speed
            if event.key == pygame.K_UP:
                lead_y_change = -moving_speed
            if event.key == pygame.K_DOWN:
                lead_y_change = moving_speed

        elif event.type == pygame.KEYUP:
            if event.key == pygame.K_RIGHT or pygame.K_LEFT or pygame.K_UP or pygame.K_DOWN:
                lead_x_change = 0
                lead_y_change = 0

    lead_x += lead_x_change
    lead_y += lead_y_change



    screen.fill(white)
    pygame.draw.rect(screen, black, [lead_x, lead_y, block_size, block_size])



    pygame.display.update()
    clock.tick(FPS)



message_to_screen("You Lose", red)
```

and when i just run it that show me following

main.py:34: RuntimeWarning: use font: dlopen(/Library/Python/2.7/site-packages/pygame/font.so, 2): Library not loaded: /usr/X11/lib/libfreetype.6.dylib
  Referenced from: /Library/Frameworks/SDL_ttf.framework/Versions/A/SDL_ttf
  Reason: image not found
(ImportError: dlopen(/Library/Python/2.7/site-packages/pygame/font.so, 2): Library not loaded: /usr/X11/lib/libfreetype.6.dylib
  Referenced from: /Library/Frameworks/SDL_ttf.framework/Versions/A/SDL_ttf
  Reason: image not found)
  font = pygame.font.Font.render(None, 25)
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "main.py", line 34, in 
    font = pygame.font.Font.render(None, 25)
  File "/Library/Python/2.7/site-packages/pygame/**init**.py", line 70, in **getattr**
    raise NotImplementedError(MissingPygameModule)
NotImplementedError: font module not available
(ImportError: dlopen(/Library/Python/2.7/site-packages/pygame/font.so, 2): Library not loaded: /usr/X11/lib/libfreetype.6.dylib
  Referenced from: /Library/Frameworks/SDL_ttf.framework/Versions/A/SDL_ttf
  Reason: image not found)

Answer (score 2):

```
font = pygame.font.Font.render(None, 25)
```

Should be:

```
font = pygame.font.Font(None, 25)
```

Answer (score 0):

When you declared the variable "font": `font = pygame.font.Font.render(None, 25)`

you don't need to write:`.render` It is used to create a text object from your font.

Try this : `font = pygame.font.Font(None, 25)`